# Hiding video controls at end of playback

Tags: javascript, html, video, controls

Default behavior for the html video element causes the video controls to appear at the end of playback. Is there a way to change that behavior so that the video controls remain hidden?

I'm assuming that there is an if statement in the source code that determines if the controls are visible if the video has ended.

I've tried removing the controls when the video ends, but then the controls aren't accessible at all.

```
player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  player.removeAttribute( 'controls' );
});
```

I've tried removing the controls and then setting the controls, but the controls still appear.

```
player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  player.removeAttribute( 'controls' );
  player.setAttribute( 'controls', '' );
});
```

I've also tried just setting the controls to false, but that does the same as removing the attribute 'controls'.

```
player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  player.controls = false
});
```

Comment: Set controls to false, and on video focus/touch/mouse interaction simply add them back.

Answer (score 0):

Basically u were almost there. Just use

```
    player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      player.removeAttribute('controls');
    });
```

(removed the `video_obj`)

Comment: Oh sorry. I updated the OP. In my code the player was an object that had an attribute video_obj that was the actual video element.

Comment: great. I don't think you can do what you want to simply by using the `controls` attribute. The option from Roko C. Buljan would be the easiest...

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to view a video in loop without any controls at all.

```
<video id="player" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src=".../your/source.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```